# Using Implicit Type Class Parameters in Coq Notation

Tags: syntax, typeclass, coq, notation

I'm trying to wrap my head around type classes in Coq (I've dabbled with it in the past, but I'm a far cry from being an experienced user). As an exercise, I am trying to write a group theory library. This is what I've come up with:

```
Class Group {S : Type} {op : S → S → S} := {
  id : S;

  inverse : S → S;

  id_left {x} : (op id x) = x;
  id_right {x} : (op x id) = x;

  assoc {x y z} : (op (op x y) z) = (op x (op y z));

  right_inv {x} : (op x (inverse x)) = id;
}.
```

I am particularly fond of the implicit `S` and `op` parameters (assuming I understand them correctly).

Making some notation for inverses is easy:

```
Notation "- x" := (@inverse _ _ _ x)
  (at level 35, right associativity) : group_scope.
```

Now, I would like to make `x * y` a shorthand for `(op x y)`. When working with sections, this is straightforward enough:

```
Section Group.
Context {S} {op} { G : @Group S op }.

(* Reserved at top of file *)
Notation "x * y" := (op x y) : group_scope.
(* ... *)
End Group.
```

However, since this is declared within a section, the notation is inaccessible elsewhere. I would like to declare the notation globally if possible. The problem I am running into (as opposed to `inverse`) is that, since `op` is an implicit parameter to `Group`, it doesn't actually exist anywhere in the global scope (so I cannot refer to it by `(@op _ _ _ x y)`). This problem indicates to me that I am either using type classes wrong or don't understand how to integrate notation with implicit variables. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

### Answer (25 Jan 2018)

Based on [Anton Trunov's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48398003/1451908), I was able to write the following, which works:

```
Reserved Notation "x * y" (at level 40, left associativity).

Class alg_group_binop (S : Type) := alg_group_op : S → S → S.

Delimit Scope group_scope with group.
Infix "*" := alg_group_op: group_scope.

Open Scope group_scope.

Class Group {S : Type} {op : alg_group_binop S} : Type := {
  id : S;

  inverse : S → S;

  id_left {x} : id * x = x;
  id_right {x} : x * id = x;

  assoc {x y z} : (x * y) * z = x * (y * z);

  right_inv {x} : x * (inverse x) = id;

}.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how Pierre Castéran and Matthieu Sozeau solve this problem in [A Gentle Introduction to Type Classes and Relations in Coq](http://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/CoqArt/TypeClassesTut/typeclassestut.pdf) (§3.9.2):

> A solution from *ibid.* consists in declaring a singleton type class for representing binary operators:
>
> ```
> Class monoid_binop (A:Type) := monoid_op : A -> A -> A.
> ```
>
> *Nota*: Unlike multi-field class types, `monoid_op` is not a constructor, but a transparent constant such that `monoid_op f` can be δβ-reduced into `f`.
>
> It is now possible to declare an infix notation:
>
> ```
> Delimit Scope M_scope with M.
> Infix "*" := monoid_op: M_scope.
> Open Scope M_scope.
> ```
>
> We can now give a new definition of `Monoid`, using the type `monoid_binop A` instead of `A → A → A`, and the infix notation `x * y` instead of `monoid_op x y` :
>
> ```
> Class Monoid (A:Type) (dot : monoid_binop A) (one : A) : Type := {
>   dot_assoc : forall x y z:A, x*(y*z) = x*y*z;
>   one_left : forall x, one * x = x;
>   one_right : forall x, x * one = x
> }.
> ```

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll give this a try and let you know if I run into any issues.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a good reason why Pierre Castéran and Matthiu Sozeau deal with it that way.

But wouldn't

```
Definition group_op {S op} {G : @Group S op} := op.
Infix "*" := group_op.
```

also work here? (I only tried on two very basic test cases.)

This would spare you changing definition of `Group`.